# Stretch div to fit a gap

Tags: html, css, position, width

I'm working on a new portfolio site which has a menu that looks like this: http://cl.ly/9rJ7
The Logo and three buttons are positioned absolute and have a fixed width (which will be changed by animation with javascript later).
The div to the right should therefore fit exactly into the gap between the third button and the browsers's right edge (as seen the screenshot).

I've already tried to give it a width of 100%, a position of left:700px and the parent div an overflow: hidden, but this doesn't seem like correct css to me, since the overflow doesn't work in some browser.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Logo and three buttons are **positioned absolute and have a fixed width** .. The div to the right should therefore fit exactly into the gap between
>   the third button and the browsers's right edge .. I've already tried to give it a width of 100%, a position of left:700px

Try `position:absolute; left:700px; right:0`.

It's fine to set both the `left` and `right` properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked great and helped me out. Cheers, janik

Answer (score 0):

If you float your left elements left, then add a div with margin-left: 700, it should fill the remaining space to the right.